# OCR(Text Recognition) result from OpenCV 3.1 + tesseract 3.04 varies depending on the order of recognition

Tags: c++, opencv, text, ocr, tesseract

I'm currently using following sample code:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/textdetection.cpp

---

The weird thing is, seemingly OCR result can vary depending on the order of images I passed to ocr module.

e.g.) If there's a 100 frames of images with text, and the recognized result can be different between
- I passes each frames sequentially to tesseract module (total 100 frames)
and
- I passes each frames not in sequential order to tesseract modules (total 100 frames)

---

Ideally, both of above cases should have a same result.

I already confirmed that it is not caused by erFilter parts.  The result coming out from erFilter is exactly same.  This difference seems to be happening inside of tesseract or tesseract wrapper in openCV.

The difference can also vary from just a confidence value has small difference, to the recognized text is different.

I feel OpenCV or tesseract remembered something and affecting to new frame's OCR result, but I couldn't find any specs telling so.

Please let me know if it is normal as OpenCV/Tesseract behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to clear the adaptive data with `ClearAdaptiveClassifier()` or turn off the adaptive classifier with config variables:

```
classify_enable_learning 0
classify_enable_adaptive_matcher 0
```

See [Tesseract FAQ](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#there-are-inconsistent-results-from-tesseract-when-the-same-tessbaseapi-object-is-used-for-decoding-multiple-images).

Comment: Thanks a lot!   The issue is solved! ;)  Seemingly OpenCV's tesseract wrapper does not expose the method nor those configuration, so I needed to modify it in order to do so.

Comment: Update: seemingly, clearing adaptive data will decrease the OCR ratio in my case.  

I think that is because: 
1. I'm trying to do OCR against video with text.  
2. The first frame and the next frame has correlation.  
3. Clearing adaptive data will discard the benefit learnt from previous frame against the ambiguous letters.

But, this means, in my case, there's no solution for fluctuation though.  The only way could be serializing OCR which means I cannot use multithreaded  optimization.  Hmm...